# Rails rollback transaction for bids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollback

Hello I'm getting a rollback transaction when I try to create a Bid from the rails console. These are my models:

## Product Model

```html
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :category
 has_many :ratings
 has_many :bids

end
```

## Bid model:

```html
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :products
 belongs_to :user
 
end
```

## User model:

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :products
 has_many :ratings
 has_many :bids
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

And this is my schema:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161231124005) do

  create_table "bids", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_bids_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bids_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

end
```

Although I tried to create like so: Bid.create(amount: 500, user_id: 1, product_id:6) it doesn't save because of the rollback transaction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't really help. You should also add the logs.
Before posting any logs, I'd try `b = Bid.new(amount: 500, user_id: 1, product_id: 6)` and `b.save` in the console. After that, do `b.errors` and see what's causing the rollback.

EDIT: Add `.save`.

EEDIT: For anyone experiencing the same problem, the issue was with the `Bid` model referencing a `Product` wrong.
When using `belongs_to`, the model should be singular, not plural. Ex: `belongs_to: apple` not `belongs_to: apples`

Comment: OK, so by doing the b.errors I'm getting: => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000052e1418 @base=#<Bid id: nil, amount: 500, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1, product_id: 6>, @messages={}, @details={}>

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the save before doing `b.errors`.. So, before doing `b.errors`, do `b.save`

Comment: From typing b.errors.full_messages I get an empty array so then I tried to do User.first.products.find(5).bids.push(b)

But I get commit transaction => false

Comment: OK, so I did b.save and then b.errors. Then I get the following: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000052ea518 @base=#<Bid id: nil, amount: 500, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1, product_id: 6>, @messages={:products=>["must exist"]}, @details={:products=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

Comment: Well, there's your error. You can't reference a Product that doesn't exist. So, before you create a Bid, you need a Product which has the ID of 6.

Comment: I have that product, I don't know what is lacking. This is the product: #<Product id: 6, title: "Normal sunglasses", description: "Geeky glasses", image_url: "sunglasses.png", price: 10, deadline: "2016-12-09 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-12-31 13:33:22", updated_at: "2016-12-31 13:33:22", user_id: 1, category_id: 4>

Comment: I did it I find thanks to your suggestions what was missing : optional: true to the belongs_to in the Bid model.

Comment: Also, I think your problem might be this `belongs_to: products` which should be `belongs_to: product` . Also, again, you shouldn't add `optional: true` your association doesn't look like a Bid shouldn't have a Product, always.

Comment: Ok, so if you want you can paste this answer so I can put the tick if it works in that case ;)

Comment: @Defoe , I've edited my answer to include the actual fix. Thanks